# i cant get my script to wp as there is nothing appear in wp html when inspect it

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, wordpress

I tried everything but I could not solve this issue i do not know what is the problem

here is the code in function.php file ;

```
<?php

  function perfection_styles() {  
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.min.css');
    }


  function perfection_scripts() {         
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('popper-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), false, true);  // to know those parameters go to codex and search for this function
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), false, true);
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'perfection_styles');
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'perfection_scripts');

 ?>
```

Comment: make sure you have a correct path of folders and assets. also are you working on child theme?

Answer (score 0):

it was a stupid mistake i named the file function.php instead of functions.php